# Why do bees fly inside the gaps between the decoration on the exterior wall of a building and the wall?

Tags: zoology, ethology, bees

My house has decorations around the windows on the exterior wall:[image]

There are gaps between those decorations and the bricks of the building:[image]

During the summer, there are always bees looking for those gaps so they could fly into them while I rarely caught them flying out. I wonder why do they do that? What do they do inside? Is there anything I should do about this situation?

I guess that maybe they want to stay in a cooler place since it's quite hot outside? However, it's also worth noting that they seem to be interested in only one particular side of one particular window since I have never seen this happening to other windows of my house.

Comment: Bees often nest in rocks and in soil, i.e. cliffs and rodents nests. Those gaps are a good shelter for a bee, from sun and rain.

Comment: @DeltaEnfieldWaid that sounds like the start of an answer.

Answer (score -1):

They just want to escape from.the heat. If there are no trees near your area, the bees can make a hive to live in. The bees don't constantly fly around; they only do so to gather food (or looking for a partner to mate).

Regarding the particular side of window, I'm not sure, may be that part is a little dry or (damp). What I mean is that the microenvironment of that crack may be more likeable to the bees, though that is just my wild guess.

Hope you found your answer. Thanks for reading.